# Problem with increment variable and stored procedure to check duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, procedure

I have problem with my `procedure`. I have table `oferty_in` which contain fields (id, status, ..., id_om). I want procedure which check `if exist` rows with the same `id_om`.

If exist, delete rows `where status = 'N'` (N - new).

My procedure almost works, but i have problem with iterate in loop. Every time I run my procedure ,procedure delete a half of rows. I don't know where is problem...

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE check_duplicates_oferty_in()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_id_del BIGINT;

SELECT count(*) INTO n FROM oferty_in where status_oferty = 'N';

SET i=0;

WHILE i<n DO 
IF EXISTS (SELECT id_om FROM oferty_in group by id_om having count(*) >= 2 LIMIT i,1) THEN
SELECT id_om INTO v_id_del FROM oferty_in group by id_om having count(*) >= 2 LIMIT i,1;
DELETE from oferty_in where id_om = v_id_del and status_oferty = 'N';
END IF;
SET i=i+1;

END WHILE;
END
//
```

I try also:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT id_om FROM oferty_in group by id_om having count(*) >= 2 LIMIT i,1) THEN
    SELECT id_om INTO v_id_del FROM oferty_in group by id_om having count(*) >= 2 LIMIT i,1;
    DELETE from oferty_in where id_om = v_id_del and status_oferty = 'N';
    SET i=i+1;
    ELSE 
    SET i=i+1;
    END IF;
```

But it's the same. 
Every time half of rows.  I use counter 'i' and `while loop` to iterate row by row on rows in `oferty_in` when `status = 'N'`. Anyone have a idea what I did wrong? Thanks for help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to delete rows with `status` = 'N' when `id_om` is duplicated.

> I want procedure which check if exist rows with the same id_om. If exist, delete rows where status = 'N' (N - new).

Non-working code doesn't generally help explain logic, so this is what I am going by.

You definitely do not need a looping construct for this, nor a cursor:

```
delete o
    from oferty_in o join
         (select o2.id_om
          from oferty_in o2
          group by o2.id_om
          having count(*) > 1 and sum(status = 'N') > 0
         ) o2
         on o.id_om = o2.id_om
    where o.status = 'N';
```